# React Native: Specify which array item to modify in reducer (using React Immutability helpers)

Tags: arrays, react-native, redux, immutability, reducers

I'm currently importing this library:

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';
```

Here is my list:

> [{id: 1, title: "some title"}, {id: 2, title: "some other title"}]

And my action:

> action.type: 'change_title'
>   
>   action.payload: [2, "some new title"]

The first parameter in action.payload refers to the **id** of the array I would like to change

Here is my reducer code:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'change_title':
      return update(state, {
        0: {
          title: { $set: action.payload[1] }
        }
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

As you can see, in it's current state my reducer function *always* changes the "title" value in the *first array*, but I would like to know: How can I specify which array to modify based on the "id" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at least two ways I think. First, using `update()`, you need to find the index of the item to update using [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
const index = state.findIndex(x => x.id === action.payload[0]);

case 'change_title':
  return update(state, {
    [index]: {
      title: { $set: action.payload[1] }
    }
  });
```

Or just using map:

```
case 'change_title':
    return state.map(item ==> {
        if(item.id !== action.payload[0]) {
            return item;
        }

        return {
            ...item,
            title: action.payload[1]
        };
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because what that is doing is finding the array in position action.payload[0], as opposed to the array with id==action.payload[0]. So, for example, if action.payload[0] == 2 i get "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" as there is not a third array

Comment: Works now. Thanks!